Where to locate SpamAssassin debug log?
Sorry if this question is stupid.
I am writing my own perl module for SpamAssassin and I want to debug if my code is working as intended.
I have made the file checklink.pre that is located in the /etc/spamassassin folder.
It has the following content:
loadplugin CheckLink /root/spamassassin/CheckLink.pm

The content of CheckLink.pm is short and sweet, since it is right now just a proof of concept.
package CheckLink;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin;
use Mail::SpamAssassin::Logger;

our @ISA = qw(Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin);

sub new {
    my ($class, $mailsa) = @_;
    $class = ref($class) || $class;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($mailsa);
    bless ($self, $class);

    $self->register_eval_rule("check_web_links");

    return $self;
}

sub check_web_links {
    my $body = shift;
    Mail::SpamAssassin::Logger::info("Body: \n\n$body\n\n\n");

    my @links = $body =~ m{https?:\/\/([^\/\.]+\.)+[^\/=?]+}g;

    foreach my $link (@links)
    {
        Mail::SpamAssassin::Logger::info("Link: $link\n");
    }

    return 1;
}

Running spamassassin -D --lint gives me amongst others these two lines:
...
dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/checklink.pre
...
dbg: plugin: loading CheckLink from /root/spamassassin/CheckLink.pm
...

Hence I know that my code is being loaded by SpamAssassin, but the real question is my code inspecting any mails?
That is why I am using Mail::SpamAssassin::Logger for debugging purpose.
I have the following rules in my local.cf file:
rawbody     WEB_LINK   eval:check_web_links()
describe    WEB_LINK   Checking mail for suspicious links
score       WEB_LINK   0.0

However when I test SpamAssassin by passing a mail containing links by calling spamc -R I cannot see any scores from SpamAssassin containing the WEB_LINK symbol.
So my question is:
Where do I find the output from Mail::SpamAssassin::Logger?
My server is running amongst other Amavis that is passing mails on to SpamAssassin.
I have enabled $log_level = 1 and $sa_debug = 1 in Amavis.
However I cannot see any additional output in /var/log/mail.log.
All I get when running spamc is the following output in my mail log:
Aug  7 21:50:30 vps3 spamd[1205069]: spamd: result: . 3 - DKIMWL_WL_MED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_EF,FROM_FMBLA_NEWDOM28,HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,SPF_HELO_NONE,T_KAM_HTML_FONT_INVALID,URIBL_GREY scantime=0.9,size=16446,user=root,uid=65534,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=42004,mid=<dVr9e7fFQaOhWiwYuhJhRg@geopod-ismtpd-3>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no

